# How to add XSL namespace custom tags

Tags: xslt

I have a source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
<PublishANZINCIDENTESB xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2013-02-25T23:25:35+00:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1361834735434709840" maximoVersion="7 1 20110105-1024 V7118-37" event="1"><ANZINCIDENTESBSet><INCIDENT action="Replace"></INCIDENT></ANZINCIDENTESBSet></PublishANZINCIDENTESB></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to change to target XML by adding namespace and header to the tag. The output XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s600="http://LIB_ISM_WPS/S600_PublishANZINCIDENT_Service_INT" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>
<s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation><PublishANZINCIDENTESB xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2013-02-25T23:25:35+00:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1361834735434709840" maximoVersion="7 1 20110105-1024 V7118-37" event="1"><ANZINCIDENTESBSet><INCIDENT action="Replace"></INCIDENT></ANZINCIDENTESBSet></PublishANZINCIDENTESB></s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSL I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:s600="http://LIB_ISM_WPS/S600_PublishANZINCIDENT_Service_INT" >
 <s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation>
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="s600:{name()}" namespace="http://LIB_ISM_WPS/S600_PublishANZINCIDENT_Service_INT">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone please help me as soon as possible as it is getting my head around?

Answer (score 0):

From your input and output examples it looks like you simply want to wrap an `s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation` element around the content of the `soapenv:Body` but otherwise leave the content unchanged.  You can achieve this with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:s600="http://LIB_ISM_WPS/S600_PublishANZINCIDENT_Service_INT"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soapenv:Body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- If the namespace declaration absolutely _must_ be on the Envelope 
       you could uncomment this extra template -->
  <!--
  <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope">
    <soapenv:Envelope>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
  -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce the output you're looking for, except that the `xmlns:s600` declaration will be on the `s600:PublishANZINCIDENTESBOperation` element rather than on the `soapenv:Envelope`, but this shouldn't matter to downstream components provided they are using a proper XML parser to process the data rather than treating it as text. Uncomment the third template if it is really important to have the declaration on the envelope instead.

Comment: As soon as I have attached the above xsl with all three templates, I get the same result no transformation happened.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><PublishANZINCIDENTESB xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="h
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2013-03-30T00:59:28+00:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1364605169180426510" maximoVersion="7 1 20110105-1024 V7118-37
" event="1">
  <ANZINCIDENTESBSet>
    <INCIDENT action="Replace">

Comment: I tried using the website to test the above xsl http://xslttest.appspot.com/ ... but still the result is not appropriate as required.

Comment: @user2224241 the `document('')` trick doesn't always work, depending how the processor is configured. I've edited the answer with an alternative implementation of the "third template".